# OOP: Class with huge number of members, how do I properly encapsulate them?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, oop

I'm mostly a C developer who is working with C++ right now and having a hard time getting into the OOP mind-set.

Here's my problem, I have a GUI with a bunch of different fields that represent data on an external USB device. There are going to be more than 100 fields, and yes that's crazy but it is what it is and it can't change. I need to be able to edit them in the GUI and send them to the device, or read them from the device and update the GUI fields.

I'm building a large class with a bunch of members that represent each field. What would be a good way of writing the fields>class>device and reading the device>class>fields, without having to make a bunch of get/set methods for each member?

I'm reading a lot about OOP and it seems getters and setters are going about OOP the wrong way. But in this instance, how else could I do it?

I thought this may be one way, but it has the serious drawback having functions with a crap-ton of parameters. I don't even know if it's legal to have that many parameters, I've never had a reason to try that before.

```
class vars
{
public:
    //read data from the device and update private members
    bool device_to_class();
    //call each of fields "setValue" function via pointer, one for each var
    void class_to_field(
        void(*set_field1)(int), 
        void(*set_field2)(int),
        //...
        void(*set_field100)(int)
        );
    //set each class member based on field
    void field_to_class(
        int var1,
        int var2,
        //...
        int var100
        );
    //write data from class to the device
    void class_to_device();
private:
    int var1;
    int var2;
    //...
    int var100;
}
```

Or should I just have a class function that takes a 'Ui' pointer (I'm using Qt, it's a pointer to the GUI class) and sets/gets all the GUI fields internal to the `vars` class?

```
void class_to_field(Ui::MainWindow *ui);
void field_to_class(Ui::MainWindow *ui);
```

Then of course have consistent naming for all of the ui fields.

Need advice from some OOP wizards out there :)

EDIT: Not all of the class members are of one type. I have arrays, 16bit ints, and a couple complicated structs...

Comment: If the fields are with fixed size, you can define a struct with all the fields, then use `memcpy` to copy the struct.

Comment: Can you organize some of the 100+ fields into small classes? This keeps you from having a god class. Have you looked into using something like the builder pattern?

Comment: You might want to treat the field names / types as a schema... ie. write a single class that implements the marshall/unmarshall and define the structure as data with one instance of your Field class per data property...

Comment: You don't like containers?

Comment: Well if you need to edit 100 values which are independent from each other with no logic involved then I do not see the point in having a class field for each, I would use a QMap

Comment: @Mine: That doesn't help move data from the class to the fields though :(

Comment: @Derek: All the data is read/written to the USB device through a single command, so I would prefer to keep it all together. Breaking it up into separate classes doesn't help move that data from the classes to the fields.

Comment: @BadZen: Could you elaborate on your comment? I'm very new to OOP, but what I'm getting from your comment is that I should define all of the fields in the same class as I store all the data? I don't know if that can be easily done in Qt, since all the fields are designed in the ui XML.

Comment: @Beta: Sure, could you elaborate on how a container would help here? I want to move data from some class/container/map/whatever into separate fields in the GUI, how it's stored is less important to me.

Comment: @Marco: Sure, but like Beta's answer I'm more concerned about moving data to the fields in the GUI. All of the values in the class are read from the device at the same time, so that's the relationship they have to each other.

Comment: I know nothing about passing data to XML, but I'm sure the C++ code is simpler and easier to maintain if you iterate through a container, rather than recite 100 variable names.

Comment: I'm with Beta on using containers. You say you don't care about how it is stored, but you are missing the point that how it is stored addresses your issue of "...without having to make a bunch of get/set methods for each member". You could use a `map` if you have something to use as a key. You could use a `vector` and add your `vars` to it as you read them in -- no get/set functions required!

Comment: @Beta Ok, so another problem I have is that they aren't all ints, some are large arrays, some are uints of different widths, etc. I can probably find a container to hold them all, but what would be the easiest way to move that data to each GUI field?

Should I just make the container public and let the GUI class iterate through it? I'm thinking that's probably the least effort method here.

Comment: The way to reduce *effort* spent on this code is to expend effort now to produce clean code; this will save effort in the long run. If you cut corners now, someone will have to pay for it later.